# String matches does not work for special char "/"

Tags: java, pattern-matching

I have a requirement wherein I need to match and list a few objects based on the data provided in the filter.
The user might also enter a regex for the match.

**For example**:
As list of Strings I have: `"test","detest","test0/1/1"`

**Filter 1**:
`"te"` ---> prints all the elements in the list

**Filter 2**:
`"te*"` --- > Prints only "test","detest" and not the third element.

I want to match the char "`/`" as well

I want the below filters also to give me a matched result:

```
te*0/*

*st*
```

Code-snippet of what I've tried so far:

```
import java.net.URLDecoder;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

public class StringMatch {

    static List<String> values = Arrays.asList("test","detest","test0/1/1");

    public static Collection<String> query(String queryStr, List<String> values) {
        String orgQueryStr = queryStr;
        queryStr = queryStr.replaceAll("\\*", "\\\\w*");
        queryStr = "\\w*" + queryStr + "\\w*"; 
        System.out.println(queryStr);
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++) {
            String str = values.get(i);
            String str1 = str.toLowerCase();
            //System.out.println("Search string : " + str1 + " QueryString : " + queryStr + " Original : " + orgQueryStr);
            if (str1.matches(queryStr) || str1.contains(orgQueryStr)){
                //System.out.println("Matched !!");
                list.add(str);
            }  
            else{
                //System.out.println("Did not match " + str1);
            }
        }
        if (list.isEmpty())
            return null;
        else
            return list;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String queryStr = "te*";
        System.out.println(URLDecoder.decode(queryStr));
        queryStr = URLDecoder.decode(queryStr);
        System.out.println(query(queryStr.toLowerCase(), values));
    }
}
```

Comment: The thing is, `\w` does not match `/`. What type of characters do you expect? Non-whitespace? Then use `\S`. Or just `.` to match any. See [this demo](http://ideone.com/MTEqk1).

Comment: Why are you using `replaceAll()`? It takes a Regex. You can use `replace()` instead.

Comment: Does `queryStr = ".*" + queryStr.replace("*", ".*") + ".*"` instead fix it?

Comment: Wiktor's answer below worked for me , which is similar to your solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\w` does not match `/`, it only matches alphanumeric and an underscore characters.

By looking at your code, I believe you want to match *any* character with a `*` in the filter. Any character but a newline can be matched with `.`.

Use

```
queryStr= queryStr.replaceAll("\\*+", ".*");
queryStr = ".*" + queryStr + (queryStr.endsWith(".*") ? "" : ".*");
```

See the [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/MTEqk1)

If your `*` in the filter should only match any characters but whitespace, use `\S` instead of a `.`:

```
queryStr= queryStr.replaceAll("\\*", "\\\\S*");
queryStr = "\\S*" + queryStr + (queryStr.endsWith("\\S*") ? "" : "\\S*");
```

Comment: @Shaik: Please check my approach. It can prove valid unless you specify any more restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

The forward slash "/" in your search string needs to be escaped (because it can be treated as a special character which is then consequently not being matched). So basically you would need to modify your expressions to something like :

```
static List<String> values = Arrays.asList("test","detest","test\\/1\\/1");
```

Edit: Added the escape for the backslashes as well

Comment: I don't think so. Are you sure?

Comment: I know so... 1) Java ain't JavaScript and 2) the forward slash is not a special regex character in any language (it's a *delimiter* in some)

Comment: Sorry I just took over the OP's wording for "special char" w/o thinking. And I did forget to escape the backslash as well :)

Comment: ... which you do not have to escape at all.

Comment: Data is dynamic and to very precise its list of ports what i get from a device which have to be filtered and they are delimited with /

Answer (score 0):

Exact alphabetic order match will work with following two lines

```
    queryStr= queryStr.replaceAll("\\*+", ".*");
    queryStr = (queryStr.startsWith(".*") ? ".*" : "") + queryStr + (queryStr.endsWith(".*") ? "" : ".*");
```

Also this line has to be modified now

```
   if (str1.matches(queryStr) || str1.contains(orgQueryStr)){
```

to

```
   if (str1.matches(queryStr)){




Ex : 

 list of Strings: "test","detest","test0/1/1"
```

**Filter 1:**

```
     "te" ---> Prints "test","test0/1/1"
```

**Filter 2:**

```
     "te*" --- > Prints "test","test0/1/1"
```

**Filter 3:**

```
     "*te"

    Prints  all
```